# Foundation CSS put a space at the bottom of my html page

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I have designed a webpage with HTML using the Foundation CSS framework. My page has a white space at the bottom for some reason.

It disappears when I remove 
`.row:after`, `.row:before { display:table; }` or `.row:after {clear:both;}`.

Comment: any code for us to refer????

Comment: Have you checked to make sure there is no padding being applied anywhere?

Comment: This is not a padding issue for sure but I have overridden the width of the .rows.

Comment: Are you saying that Zurb puts `.row:after, .row:before { display: table; }` in the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where there was random space at the bottom of the page while using the Foundation Framework. It was easily fixed by deleting this from the foundation.css file:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```